# update row without deleting previous values in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

One of my table has a field user_ids and the value of the field like 2,3

```
group_id| user_ids  
--------|------------   
1       | 2,3  
--------|------------  
2       | 5,8
```

I want to update the field without deleting the current value. For ex. If I need to add 5 for group_id id 1, then 2,3 should be like 2,3,5

I m using this query:

```
UPDATE users_group SET user_ids = CONCAT( SUBSTRING( user_ids, 1, CHAR_LENGTH( user_ids ) -1 ) , ',5' ) WHERE group_id =1
```

But it is deleting previous value with comma.

```
group_id| user_ids  
--------|------------   
1       | ,5  
--------|------------  
2       | 5,8
```

can anyone suggest the right way for this?

Comment: The right way would be to normalise the table properly, rather than storing comma-separated values in a column.... but why are you concatenating a substring of the column with the new value to add?

Comment: can you please explain this how? I mean with the help of mysql query.

Comment: You should have a table with group_id and user_id, and store each group_id/user_id in a separate row of that table

Answer (score 3):

Can you not just concatenate it on, rather than trying to split it up first?

```
UPDATE users_group 
SET user_ids = CONCAT_WS(',', user_ids, '5' ) 
WHERE group_id =1
```

But this does suggest a badly normalised database design. Generally a comma separated list should instead be stored as rows on another table (ie, one row per value in the list) as suggested by Mark Baker.

EDIT - If you want to only have a single copy of any id in each user_ids field, irrespective of how many times you try to insert it, and you want to be able to add multiple ids at once:-

```
UPDATE users_group a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 3 AS an_id
    UNION 
    SELECT 4
) b
ON FIND_IN_SET(b.an_id, a.user_ids) = 0
SET a.user_ids = CONCAT_WS(',', a.user_ids, b.an_id ) 
WHERE a.group_id =1
```

EDIT again - if you have a table of users containing the ids then you can select the ids from that where the id is one of those you want to add.

Something like this.

```
UPDATE users_group a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id
    FROM users
    WHERE id IN (3, 4)
) b
ON FIND_IN_SET(b.id, a.user_ids) = 0
SET a.user_ids = CONCAT_WS(',', a.user_ids, b.id ) 
WHERE a.group_id =1
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Kickstart. But it results in duplicate values as 2,1,4,3,4,3,4 for user_ids field if I use your solution as this: UPDATE users_group SET user_ids = CONCAT_WS( ',', user_ids, 3,4 ) WHERE group_id =1;

Comment: Is that if you run it multiple times? As if run once that should not happen? Are you trying to ensure that any id only occurs once in the list?

Comment: yes exactly I want the values coming in user_ids field should come only ones. no duplicate values

Comment: Added a suggestion to cope with this.

Comment: kickstart in my case 3,4 are coming from a varaible (say $users). i.e dynamicaly using php. I cant use my variable in your suggested query. For static values it works fine

Comment: Just dynamically create the sub query that has the ids in it.. You have already had to dynamically create the query with the example code where you are adding a variable number of fields in the CONCAT_WS function.

Comment: Thanks. That was exactly what I want.

Comment: i got it useful. +10

Answer (score 2):

```
update table1 set name = concat(name, ', ', 5) WHERE group_id =1
```

Comment: but it concat just 1 value. If there are more than one values than what should I do?

Comment: then add multiple values separated with comma inside `concat`  function.

Comment: But than it results in duplicate values as 2,1,4,3,4,3,4 for user_ids field if I use your solution as this: UPDATE users_group SET user_ids = CONCAT_WS( ',', user_ids, 3,4 ) WHERE group_id =1; as the query suggested by kickstart

Answer (score 2):

Please try this query. It may be useful for you.

```
UPDATE users_group SET user_ids = CONCAT( user_ids , ',5' ) WHERE group_id =1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query:

```
UPDATE users_group 
SET user_ids = CONCAT( user_ids , ',5' ) 
WHERE group_id =1
```