# check if comma separated values exist in table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table: users_group

```
id | group_id | user_ids
---|----------|---------
1  |   1      | 3
2  |   1      | 2
3  |   3      | 2
4  |   2      | 3
5  |   2      | 4
6  |   2      | 2
```

condition is that user_ids can be inserted only once. But in above case it is inserted for more than one group_id.

I am using this query to insert users_id field within foreach loop:
INSERT INTO users_group (group_id, user_ids) VALUES(2,3)

how can I prevent to insert duplicate user_ids

Is there any better query?

Comment: Why not start by normalising your database so you don't have CSV id columns?

Comment: You should rethink your schema and use relations not comma-separated strings. That's not how you use relational databases.

Comment: Do you remember the comments about normalizing your database when you asked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32605791/update-row-without-deleting-previous-values-in-mysql)? If you'd followed that advice, then you wouldn't be encountering all these problems!

Comment: thanks for the suggestion Mark. I had changed the procedure accordingly. But now what to do to remove duplicate value entries

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is a better way to solve this problem, but the solution doesn't imply the query.

Instead of `user_id` column you should create a new column called `user_id` and add data like this:

```
id | group_id | user_id
1  |   1      | 3
2  |   1      | 4
3  |   2      | 3
4  |   2      | 4
5  |   2      | 2
6  |   3      | 2
7  |   3      | 3
8  |   3      | 4
```

This is called `Many to Many` relation and makes everything easier. After that you need to only JOIN the tables;

Comment: I have edited my question according to your suggestion. please reply to my doubt.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to start by creating  unique index on the column that you want to have only unique values . In this case that it would be the  `user_ids` column.